# field update using workflow and formula function

Tags: workflow, formula, field-update, actionfunction

In standard object Case there is Description field and there is text being inserted i'm looking for specific text/string "First Name" and i would like to move everything from the left of "First Name" to a custom text field. Is it possible with using workflow and How?

Comment: If the specific text/string are being populated from a field? I assume it is not hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, you want to move part of your Description field to another text field? Here are a couple of formulae for you:

1. LEFT(Description, FIND("First Name",Description)-1)
2. RIGHT(Description, LEN(Description)-FIND("First Name",Description)+1)

Here is a string of text:

"Location: Boston First Name: Bob Last Name: Jones"

- Formula 1 will output "Location: Boston "
- Formula 2 will output "First Name: Bob Last Name: Jones"

Thus, you can create a workflow with two field updates:

1. Set Text__c equal to the value of formula 1
2. Set Description equal to the value of formula 2

Tweak as needed, e.g. if you want to remove trailing spaces wrap it in a TRIM function.

Comment: Not working :( not doing anything. here is the text sample in the Description field:


Agent Name: Luis Smith 
Agent Email: lsmith@hotmail.com 
First Name: h

Comment: Explain a bit further. After the workflow runs, what would you like in Description, and what would you like in the new text field? I tested those formulas in my dev environment and they produced the result I provided above.

Comment: I didn't have the workflow activated. It's working.thanks.